# Python/SQL - Window function in Python - Summing all rows between current row and unbounded following rows

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, window-functions

I am looking the pythonic approach to handling window functions. I have three colums - Col1 , Col2 are categorical and Date respectively and Col3 is numerical. I want to find the moving sum over the current row and unbounded following n rows of the numeric column, grouped at Col1 summed over Col2 i.e. Date
[Image Attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w84b.jpg)

| Date(MM/DD/YYYY) | ID | Amt | Desired Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2016 | 1 | 10 | 333 |
| 11/01/2016 | 1 | 5 | 323 |
| 12/01/2016 | 1 | 20 | 318 |
| 01/01/2017 | 1 | 50 | 298 |
| 02/01/2017 | 1 | 60 | 248 |
| 03/01/2017 | 1 | 20 | 188 |
| 04/01/2017 | 1 | 0 | 168 |
| 05/01/2017 | 1 | 0 | 168 |
| 06/01/2017 | 1 | 38 | 168 |
| 07/01/2017 | 1 | 60 | 130 |
| 08/01/2017 | 1 | 50 | 70 |
| 09/01/2017 | 1 | 20 | 20 |

Please help out :)

I could not find anything related  to unbounded following n rows. Though preceding n rows is pretty straightforward using the df.rolling method

Comment: You should provide a clear example of input/output in a reproducible format.

Comment: You don't literally mean unbounded.  What determines the window size?

Comment: An image is not reproducible. Please provide a DataFrame constructor as text.

Comment: I think you forgot 8 in your sum

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly, and assuming sorted dates, you need a reversed [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```py
df['Desired Column'] = df[::-1].groupby('ID')['Amt'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   Date(MM/DD/YYYY)  ID  Amt  Desired Column
0        10/01/2016   1   10             341
1        11/01/2016   1    5             331
2        12/01/2016   1   20             326
3        01/01/2017   1   50             306
4        02/01/2017   1   60             256
5        03/01/2017   1   20             196
6        04/01/2017   1    0             176
7        05/01/2017   1    0             176
8        06/01/2017   1   38             176
9        07/01/2017   1   68             138
10       08/01/2017   1   50              70
11       09/01/2017   1   20              20
```